# Can't Disable SMB 2/3 Signing between Windows 10 and Windows Server 2019

Tags: filesystems, network-share, windows-10, server-message-block, windows-server-2019

I've been having some strange file copy issues between a Windows 10 client and Window Server 2019 system (DC/Fileserver).

I don't want to explain that issue in detail here other than to say it appears it is caused by SMB signing (random Invalid Signature on file copies).
I have validated that the issue goes away when using SMB encryption (implemented by enabling RequirePrivacy=1 in Hardened UNC path setting).  My Wireshark capture shows in the Negotiate Protocol Response (SMB 3.1.1 is used dialect):

```
Security mode: 0x03, Signing enabled, Signing required
.... ...1 = Signing enabled: True
.... ..1. = Signing required: True
```

However according to [Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4458042/reduced-performance-after-smb-encryption-or-smb-signing-is-enabled)

> When requiring SMB Encryption, SMB Signing is not used, regardless of settings. SMB Encryption implicitly provides the same integrity guarantees as SMB Signing

So, in effect I have disabled signing by using encryption instead.  With this enabled my "issue" doesn't exist.

I would like to try this without the use of encryption and instead with signing disabled.  Unfortunately, I can't get windows to turn this off.  I have done the following:

1) Configured my local Windows 10 client's security policy:

**Microsoft network client: Digitally sign communications (always) = DISABLED**

**Microsoft network client: Digitally sign communications (if server agrees) = DISABLED**

(The second setting [according to Microsoft](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/josebda/2010/12/01/the-basics-of-smb-signing-covering-both-smb1-and-smb2/) shouldn't even be required for SMB2 communication)

2) Configured my Windows Server 2019 DC via the Domain Controllers GPO:

**Microsoft network server: Digitally sign communications (always) = DISABLED**

**Microsoft network server: Digitally sign communications (if client agrees) = DISABLED**

(The second setting [according to Microsoft](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/josebda/2010/12/01/the-basics-of-smb-signing-covering-both-smb1-and-smb2/) shouldn't even be required for SMB2 communication)

Based on my understanding that should be all that is required to disable SMB2 signing.  However I have additionally tried the following:

Disabled SecuritySignature on the DC's SMB:

**- Set-SmbServerConfiguration -EnableSecuritySignature $false**

**- Set-SmbServerConfiguration -RequireSecuritySignature $false**

I'm not sure if the above actually deal with SMB2 signing or only SMB1, but I set them anyway in addition to disabling these on my client (Set-SmbClientConfiguration settings)

I have also tried to set the UNC Hardening keys on my Windows 10 system to **RequireIntegrity=0**.

None of these settings work to disable SMB signing.  The best I get in my Wireshark capture Negotiate Protocol Response is:

```
Security mode: 0x01, Signing enabled
.... ...1 = Signing enabled: True
.... ..0. = Signing required: False
```

So I've succeeded in disabling the requirement for signing, but I can't actually get the signing to turn off.

I can't find anything that states that signing can't be disabled, so either there is a bug - or I'm missing something.

Help?

Comment: Any luck? Thought I'd take a stab by asking [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/gb2gta/how_to_disable_smb_signing_encryption_for_windows/) as well.

Comment: Nothing.  I've posted related issues on MS forums:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/16b8de48-b711-4014-8a85-e3363b05cfab/error-0x80090006-invalid-signature-copying-files-from-windows-server-2019-to-windows-10-smb3?forum=ws2019

and

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f7d74b9b-f994-4118-b46e-abce0b62fa60/unable-to-disable-secure-negotiate-for-smb3-on-windows-server-2019-windows-10?forum=ws2019

But the help there is non-existent.  MS is getting worse and worse in not updating documentation as the product evolves, so there is no information anywhere.